# I want to split a numbered list. The numbers in a increasec order are delimiters

Tags: sql-server, parsing, design-patterns, split

I have a huge database of a regional language dictionary where the field "meaning" is a numbered list to show multiple meanings of the same word. I want to split it into a different table. How do I split?
String_split expected one fixed delimiter but here the delimiter is an incremental number.

e.g.

```
  Word Meaning
  ---- -------
  Good 1 fine 2 excellent 3 great 
  Big  1 large 2 huge 3 giant
```

Each individula meaning in the meaning list can be one word or a sentence as well.
Please help me.

Comment: My best advice would be to use anything other than T-SQL for this. Power BI, client-side regex, take your pick. T-SQL's poor string processing can solve this only at considerable expense of ingenuity (especially if the solution has to perform well).

Comment: I hate to be the barer of bad news but this just screams poor database design. storing delimited data in a single column is never a good idea, and storing it without a fixed delimiter is an even worst idea. You really should change this database design.

Comment: The point everyone is trying to make is that your design violates 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. This needs to be two tables at a minimum. Your Meaning column is storing rows from what should be another table. And this poor design is why you are struggling to get the data that you want. When the database is properly normalized querying the data is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you could just use `STRING_SPLIT` here and just exclude rows that are an `int`:

```sql
SELECT V.Word,
       SS.[Value] AS Meaning
FROM (VALUES('Good','1 fine 2 excellent 3 great'),
            ('Big ','1 large 2 huge 3 giant'))V(Word,Meaning)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.Meaning,' ') SS
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.[value]) IS NULL;
```

---

Seems that a meaning can have multiple words. One method, therefore, is to use a JSON splitter, which means you get the ordinal position of the split values. Then you can `COUNT` the number of `int` values so far to get the meaning "number". Then you can re aggregate those words per meaning:

```sql
WITH Split AS(
    SELECT V.Word,
           OJ.*,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,OJ.[value]) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY V.Word ORDER BY CONVERT(int,OJ.[Key])) AS MeaningNo
    FROM (VALUES('Good','1 fine 2 excellent 3 great'),
                ('Big ','1 large 2 huge 3 giant 4 Not small'))V(Word,Meaning)
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(Meaning,' ','","') + '"]') OJ)
SELECT S.Word,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,S.[Value]) IS NULL THEN S.[value] END,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int,S.[Key])) AS Meaning
FROM Split S
GROUP BY S.Word,
         S.MeaningNo;
```

Comment: Works fine but only as long as no definitions actually include spaces (which none of the OP's examples do, but would seem very likely if it's a "huge database").

Comment: Yes, @JeroenMostert , I do make that assumption based on the OP's sample data. If that isn't the case, then they'll need to give better samples.

Comment: Actually, we're probably both guilty of not reading the whole question, as the OP specifically mentions that definitions can be whole sentences at the end, so no speculation needed. :P

Comment: OK, I have a solution for that then, @JeroenMostert

Comment: Better, @JeroenMostert ?

Comment: It amazes me how we something think alike. Check out what I was working on as an answer to this question on [Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b72336713c1679aeef488dff0229a7c)

Comment: Breaks instantly if the sentence contains characters that require escaping in JSON (like `"`), but fortunately that's fixable with `STRING_ESCAPE`.

Comment: I was considering `delimitedsplit8K_lead`, @ZoharPeled , however, far too many users have been trying to split values over 8K/4K characters I've reverted to use a JSON splitter by default. I wish they would just design their databases properly to start with. ;)

Comment: There's only so many assumptions I'm willing to make, @JeroenMostert . ;)

Comment: Well, there's a reason I said "considerable expense of ingenuity" in my first comment. :P

Comment: Thank you so much @ZoharPelad and Larnu. I will try using Json Splitter. 
I do understand your point regarding poor database design but this is raw data that I got as an output of OCR of a printed dictionary. I could split between Word and Meaning but the Meaning came as a numbered list from the way it is printed in any dictionary. In order to put it into a normalized database, I have to split it hence this question. Thanks a ton for your great answers.